# Are A records to NS hostnames required?

Tags: domain-name-system, a-record, ns-record

Among other things, I have the following in my delegated zone file (note, domain is NOT rwasphost.com)...

```
;
;  Zone NS records
;

@                       NS  dns1.rwasphost.com.
dns1.rwasphost.com.     A   64.222.127.135
@                       NS  dns2.rwasphost.com.
dns2.rwasphost.com.     A   207.40.153.2
```

WITH the A records, Microsoft DNS server "knows" that each NS points to the specified A... without the A records, Microsoft DNS server "figures out" what IP each NS points to (in the SOA, under "Name Servers", if the A's are undefined, the IP address has an asterisk indicating "* represents an IP address retrieved as the result of a DNS query and may not represent actual records stored on this server".)

Is there ANY reason to keep these A records?  I'm trying to migrate my DNS servers, and it seems to me that if all my zones specify NS records, and their corresponding A records, then I'll have more A's to manage when I migrate.

I'd much prefer to remove the A's as follows:

```
;
;  Zone NS records
;

@                       NS  dns1.rwasphost.com.
@                       NS  dns2.rwasphost.com.
```

Is the above still good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your domain is not `rwasphost.com` and you are not the parent domain of `rwasphost.com` (which you obviously aren't since you don't run .com) then you don't need the glue records. So your second example is fine.

Comment: Just curious, why does Microsoft DNS allow you to fill that in and save that in the SOA...`dns1.rwasphost.com.     A   64.222.127.135
`

Comment: Probably to overrule the address or avoid a separate lookup. I'm not sure.